# How can a closure outlive the main function if the entire process ends when main function ends?

Tags: rust, closures, ownership

I have below code:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let x: &'static mut [i32; 3] = Box::leak(Box::new([1, 2, 3]));
    thread::spawn(|| dbg!(&x));
}
```

When I compile it, I get below error:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `x`, which is owned by the current function
--> src\main.rs:10:19
|
10 |     thread::spawn(|| dbg!(&x));
|                   ^^       - `x` is borrowed here
|                   |
|                   may outlive borrowed value `x`
|
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
--> src\main.rs:10:5
|
10 |     thread::spawn(|| dbg!(&x));
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `x` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
|
10 |     thread::spawn(move || dbg!(&x));
|                   ++++
```

Here it tells me "closure may outlive the current function". I suppose the "current function" is the main function. But is it possible that the closure outlives the main function? When the main function ends, the entire process ends as well. This means that all threads that were spawned from this process are also terminated, regardless of whether they have finished executing or not. So how can the closure outlive the main function?

Comment: Rust doesn't see difference between `main` and any other function. Closure passed to `spawn` must be `'static`.

Comment: Note that even though `x` is `&'static`, `&x` is a reference to a static reference (`&&'static`), and as such has non-static lifetime.

Comment: You can use [std::thread::scope](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html) when you want to tell the compiler that spawned thread must be joined before current thread exists. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, but  you are not answering my question.

Comment: It is not possible that spawned thread will outlive the main one, however as I stated in my first comment rust doesn't takes that into consideration. All spawned threads using `std::thread::spawn` must take closures that are `'static`. It doesn't matter where you spawn your thread.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I think I understand your point.

Comment: Is it true that Rust considers a `'static` closure to live longer than `main`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255258/discussion-between-aleksander-krauze-and-fajela-tajkiya).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads are killed **after** the main function ended.

This sounds like nit-picking, but this distinction is important, because the ending of the main function includes the destruction of local variables. This means first the variables are destroyed, including calling their `drop()` implementations, and **then** the threads get killed.

This demonstrates that fact:

```rust
use std::{
    thread::{self, sleep},
    time::Duration,
};

struct MyStruct {}

impl Drop for MyStruct {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Drop");
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _x = MyStruct {};

    thread::spawn(|| loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(45));
        println!("Thread");
    });

    sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
}
```

```
Thread
Thread
Drop
Thread
Thread
```

Note that if the thread had a `&` (non-`mut`) reference to `_x`, inside of the `drop()` function, a `&` and a `&mut` to `_x` would exist simultaneously. Further, whatever content the variable contains will most certainly be destroyed in the `drop()` function, so having an external reference to it is most definitely undefined behaviour.

For reasons like that, the `main()` function simply gets treated as a normal function, and all the normal borrowing rules apply.

---

Those were some general words about why `main()` gets treated as a normal function, but now let's talk about your code.

It seems you tried to overcome this issue by `Box::leak`ing the variable. This is absolutely a possible way of prolonging the lifetime of a variable past the end of `main()`, but you made a mistake. The array itself is `&'static`, but the variable `x` **is not**. And when you do `&x` in your thread, you are not referencing the array, but the variable `x`, and `x` lives in `main()`.

You need to move the reference itself into the thread. Because it isn't obvious how this differs from moving the `Box` itself into the thread, I'll create a second thread for demonstration purposes:

```rust
use std::{
    thread::{self, sleep},
    time::Duration,
};

fn main() {
    let x: &'static [i32; 3] = Box::leak(Box::new([1, 2, 3]));
    let x2 = x;

    thread::spawn(move || dbg!(x));
    thread::spawn(move || dbg!(x2));

    sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
}
```

```
[src\main.rs:10] x = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
]
[src\main.rs:11] x2 = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
]
```

I also made the reference `&`, not `&mut`, to be used by two threads.
Also note that `&` references are `Copy`, making `let x2 = x;` possible. This does not clone the original array, they both point at the very same data.

When paired with a `Mutex`, this becomes obvious:

```rust
use std::{
    sync::Mutex,
    thread::{self, sleep},
    time::Duration,
};

fn main() {
    let x: &'static Mutex<[i32; 3]> = Box::leak(Box::new(Mutex::new([1, 2, 3])));
    let x2 = x;

    thread::spawn(move || {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
        let locked_x = x.lock().unwrap();
        dbg!(*locked_x);
    });
    thread::spawn(move || {
        x2.lock().unwrap()[1] = 42;
    });

    sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
}
```

```
[src\main.rs:14] *locked_x = [
    1,
    42,
    3,
]
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation and examples! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

A summary of [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255258).

Note. When I talk about "closure" I have in mind any type that implements `FnOnce() -> T`. For the sake of brevity I will use this specific class of types, since they are used most often in the following context.

The API of `std::thread::spawn` requires that spawned thread *may* outlive the thread from which it was spawned (note that this is a design choice, and there are different APIs that do not require this, for example [std::thread::scope](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html)). For this to be true, closure passed to new thread cannot capture any references which lifetime is tied to the first thread. In other words it can only hold `'static` references.

What is special about rust, is that it enforces this at the **type** level. `std::thread::spawn` has following signature:

```rust
pub fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<T>where
    F: FnOnce() -> T + Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
```

Which at the type level enforces that both closure passed to `spawn` and value it returns is `'static`.

What is important is that rust doesn't treat `main` function differently than any other function. Event if the compiler *could* reason that new thread will not outlive the main thread, this type-level API still requires all closures to be `'static`.

Also wording of the error message "closure may outlive the current function" can be a little misleading. Closures don't outlive functions. They are just values, that are valid in their *scope*, just like all the other values. In this context what is important is which **thread** can outlive which **thread**. Since `std::thread::spawn` allows spawned thread to outlive the thread from which it was called, spacial restrictions must be place upon a caller for this to be safe.